What is the differences between Webview and Html viewer packages in Android?
I removed the Webview package, and then I can't open an offline html file and txt file via the Html viewer package.
Do you know what is the relationship between them? How are they different and how do they affect together?

What are you doing? In what context? What is happening when you can't do something?

Webview and HTML viewer are two different components in Android and serve different purposes. For instance;
Webview is a view that displays webpages or HTML content within an Android App.
HTML viewer is used to properly resolve and render text that has HTML tags. The HTML text can be from a locally installed file or some HTML text from the server or URL.
The main difference is that a Webview is more powerful and has more features than the HTML viewer.
Therefore, I don't find any relation between the two and therefore, your code should work fine. You can share your code snippet for further review.
